# SQL within time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query which will query from a date range and fixed timing on the appointed devices. How could I modify the query so that the time within a + - 10minutes.
*For example* if user chosen 4:00pm and the query shall cater for 3:50pm until 4:10pm on every single day within the date range.

```
SELECT Timestamp, AVG(Value) 
FROM STATIC_SENSOR_READINGS 
WHERE 
Node_ID IN ($sdNodeList) AND  
Modality = 'Temperature' AND 
Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  // This will be the date range.
date_format(`Timestamp`, '%H:%i') = '$time'  // Specific time here
GROUP BY Timestamp
```

Comment: If you asked about the scheduled tasks, I think you should learn about `cron` here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: no it wasn't @OkiErieRinaldi it was for value retrieve before graph plotting.

Answer (score 0):

To check timestamps are "approximately" equal in mysql, you can use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function.

In your example, you need something like:

```
SELECT Timestamp, AVG(Value) 
FROM STATIC_SENSOR_READINGS 
WHERE 
Node_ID IN ($sdNodeList) AND  
Modality = 'Temperature' AND 
Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  // This will be the date range.
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTES, Timestamp, '$time')) < 10 
GROUP BY Timestamp
```

You may have to adjust time/timestamp formats to suit your needs.

Comment: Cool, sounds legit. Let me try it. Will feedback later.

Comment: will you be able to explain abit for `ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTES, Timestamp, '$time')) < 10` ? How does this line gonna work together with the previous Timestamp range?

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` should give you the time difference between the 2nd and 3rd parameters (a date will be converted to time 00:00:00 for you). In this case we are asking for the difference to be given in `MINUTES`, the first parameter.  

So, we should get back 2, 5, -40, 720 etc depending upon the value of `Timestamp` column and the supplied `$time` value - (I am assuming you provide this as a full timestamp - I can't see the rest of your code).  

We then take the `ABS()` because the difference can be + or - 10 minutes either side. Then we check that it is less than 10.